Connecting to Elasticsearch deployed on GCP via python
I'm trying to connect over HTTPS to my ElasticSearch deploy on Google Cloud Platform.
I created Virtual Machine with allow to HTTP and HTTPS traffic with default network and firewall rule (ingress, IP range 0.0.0.0/0, exposed ports tcp:9200).
Then I installed ES on my VM, change in elasticsearch.yml my host to 0.0.0.0.
(As described here: https://dzone.com/articles/elastic-search-on-google-cloud-platform)
I'm trying to connect to it using python client as follows:
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch    
es_client = Elasticsearch('https://{vm_external_ip}:9200',
                                           basic_auth=('elastic', {password}),
                                           ca_certs=cert_path)

where cert_path is path to certificate from /elasticsearch/certs/.
And I'm receiving an error:
elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by: TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError(hostname {vm_external_ip} doesn't match either of 'elasticsearch', '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1', '127.0.0.1', '{vm_internal_ip}', 'localhost'))
Is there a way to connect over HTTPS using python client to ES deployed on GCP VM via its external ip?
Best regards!

Generally you want to use DNS names rather than IP addresses to use TLS. In this case, the Elasticsearch server appears to support localhost (127.0.0.1) with the provided TLS cert. You should probably register a DNS name for your VM (IP) and get a certificate for it. You could (!) test the current deployment by port-forwarding to your VM (gcloud compute ssh .... --ssh-flag="-L 9200:localhost:9200" ) and updating the Python code to use 127.0.0.1:9200 (port-forwarded)

Yes, As @DazWilkin mentioned you need to use the dns instead of IP. Check this quickstart to create a DNS for the GCP vm.
